# Resizing image with PHP

Tags: php, image, gd, jpeg

I used a very simple code to resize image with PHP; but surprisingly it does not work for some images. The problem should be associated with imagecreatefromjpeg(), as it will generate a black image (which is of the background image).

```
$picture="test5.jpg";
$url="http://www.pokerpurist.com/uploadedImages/bettingpro/NewsImages/TN98553_Perla-Beltran.jpg";
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($url);

$new_height = $height / $width * 400;
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor(400, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, $new_height, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($image_p, $picture);
echo "<img src='$picture' />";
```

This problem happens offen, and I included an example image. What is the problem with these images leading to this problem? It seems to be a normal JPG image.

By the way, is it the simplest and most efficient way to resize image with PHP/GD2?

Comment: Your post is confusing... what exactly is the problem? Are you saying that you get a black image instead? In this case the `imagecopyresampled` has the wrong parameters set as black is the default for `imagecreatetruecolor`.

Comment: @alasdair His sample image is a PNG with jpg extension...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example image is a PNG, not JPEG. You probably need to put some detection code in place...

Edit: [exif-imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) or [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) might be of some use.

Comment: You're quite right! It seems people wrongfully name the extension of images over the web. I wondered why I never encountered this problem for local files. I did use `exif_imagetype()` to detect the correct image format.

Answer (score 2):

@By the way, is it the simplest and most efficient way to resize image with PHP/GD2?

Use [Asido](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asido): PHP Image Processing Solution

Asido supports the following features:

- pluggable drivers for GD2 (php_gd2), MagickWand (php_magickwand),
  ImageMagick extension (php_imagick) as well as ImageMagick shell
  commands
- "hack" drivers: workarounds for certain disabilities of a particular driver by using some of the other functionality provided
  by the environment
- various resize functionality: proportional resize, resize only by width or height, stretch resize, fit resize, frame resize
- watermark images, including tiling watermark and automatic scaling of large watermarks
- rotate images
- copy images onto one another
- crop images
- grayscale images
- convert images between different filetypes

If you can't access [Asido](http://asido.info/) website, you can download Asido from [SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asido/files/asido/Asido%200.0.0.1a/)

Comment: Is this faster than GD for vector drawing?